# Show that indicator function is integrable

Tags: integration, self-learning

How to show that 
$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}I(\lVert u \rVert_\infty\leq C)du\leq M<\infty$?

My intuition says that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}I(\lVert u \rVert_\infty\leq C)du\leq\int_{[-C,C]^d}1 du=(2C)^d:=M,$$

since the maximum coordinate must be less than $C$, and so the others.

Is it right?

Comment: What are $I,u$?

Comment: $u\in\mathbb{R}^d$ and $I$ the indicator function. It's equivalent to write the integral $d$ times over $\mathbb{R}$ and integrate w.r.t. $u_1,\dotsc,u_d$

Comment: Then yes, you are right.